# Countdown does not stop properly

Tags: javascript

Onclick Countdown for an Alarmclock does not stop properly. It stops at "-1:0" and not 0:00 as planed.
Tryed to solve the Problem by changing the "> < =" Operators but i dont get it right.
Maybe someone can help me with that.

```js
function startTimer() {
  let startTime = new Date().getTime();
  let fiveMinutes = 5 * 1 * 1000;
  let endTime = startTime + fiveMinutes;

  var countdown = setInterval(function count() {
    let timeLeft = endTime - new Date().getTime();
    let minutes = timeLeft / (1000 * 60);
    minutes = Math.floor(minutes);
    let seconds = (timeLeft / 1000) % 60;
    seconds = Math.round(seconds);
    let text = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    timer.innerHTML = text;

    if ((minutes <= 0) && (seconds <= 0)) {
      clearInterval(countdown);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class="timer center margin-top" id="timer">
  00:05
</div>

<div class="button center">
  <img onclick="startTimer()" img src="img/btn.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: If you use a snippet then please also use the _"Tidy"_ feature (and remove unnecessary white-space like empty lines)

Comment: I took the liberty to reduce the countdown to five seconds. Its not really necessary to wait a whole minute if only the last second is important for the question.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas. My first steps in here^^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function startTimer() {
  let startTime = new Date().getTime();
  // If its five minute  5 * 60 * 1000;
  let fiveSeconds = 5 * 1000;
  let endTime = startTime + fiveSeconds;

  var countdown = setInterval(function count() {
    let timeLeft = endTime - new Date().getTime();
    let minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    
    let seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft / 1000) % 60);
    
    // Once test is passed do the DOM manipulation
    let text = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    timer.innerHTML = text;
    
    if ((minutes <= 0) && (seconds === 0)) {
      return clearInterval(countdown);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class="timer center margin-top" id="timer">
  5:00
</div>

<div class="button center">
  <button onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem with OPs code? What have you change to make it work?

Comment: And why did you change the countdown to 5 minutes? Why are future readers supposed to wait that long until they see if this answer actually is an answer?

Comment: Changed code to populate data after checking the value. Also The variable says fiveMinutes that does not mean 5 seconds. If someone wants to test they can try in their browser console.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Counter stops at 0:1. It needs to stop at 0:00.

Comment: @Codenix-1349 made some change. Can you look at it now.

Comment: Works fine to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is only using `Math.floor(minutes)`.
try to use `Math.round(minutes)`

this is code for solve your problem :

```js
function startTimer() {
  let startTime = new Date().getTime();
  let fiveMinutes = 5 * 1 * 1000;
  let endTime = startTime + fiveMinutes;

  var countdown = setInterval(function () {
    let timeLeft = endTime - new Date().getTime();
    let minutes = timeLeft / (1000 * 60);
    minutes = Math.round(minutes);
    let seconds = (timeLeft / 1000) % 60;
    seconds = Math.round(seconds);
    let text = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    timer.innerHTML = text;

    if ((minutes <= 0) && (seconds <= 0)) {
      clearInterval(countdown);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class="timer center margin-top" id="timer">
  00:05
</div>

<div class="button center">
  <img onclick="startTimer()" img src="img/btn.png" alt="button start" />
</div>
```